# Blender - How can I create proper lighting using Radeon ProRender?

Tags: light, radeon-prorender-render-engine

Is there anyone that could tell me or point me in the right direction on how can I use/create proper lighting with **Radeon ProRender**.

I want to create objects that will be emissive/emission ,I'm kinda not sure how to do it properly ,so again I am asking for some helping hand

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should refer to [Radeon ProRender user guide](https://www2.ati.com/relnotes/radeon-prorender-for-blender.pdf), for a start...

The RPR EMISSIVE material should be what you are looking for...

[image]

To get RBR support, I suggest to refer to the [specific RBR for Blender support page](http://support.radeonprorender.com/support/solutions/16000053500)

Comment: Hey there. Well I read the PDF ,not the whole thing but the stuff I had trouble with ,there was no mention of what i needed ,I have no troubles assigning Materials ,or using node editor to make a material but I am having troubles with the Emissive materials on surfaces ,since its really hard to do it ,since I have no info on size / intensity . I hope you understand my problem .